# MPMoviePlayerController interface orientation change in full screen

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, interface-orientation

I have added MPMoviePlayerController in my view. and its working fine. and when I switch to this in full screen and change the orientation of device then no orientation change event is fired. so please can let me know how I solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you present `MPMoviePlayerController` modally so check out the -

`(void)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of your main app controller. I suppose that if you return **TRUE** just for portrait the modal controller can't rotate itself. Try to return **TRUE** for all interface orientation on your `rootViewController` and the `MPMoviePlayerController` should start to rotate.

Comment: Actually I am not using modelviewcontroller. I used addsubview for this. same video is working in small size and full screen. in full screen i am just setting isfullscreen=true for this. thx

Comment: Sorry I confused the MPMoviePlayerViewController but the MPMoviePlayerController expose the view so if your viewController, that hosts your video, rotate correctly you should be able to see it rotated.